# Can jQuery $.get trigger javascript code on second page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two pages. The first is a form that allows the user to customize an image. In this example, they are selecting the color Orange:

```
var color = "ff6600";
$.get("page2.php?color=" + color, function(data) {

}
```

My second page uses Javascript to generate new images by creating a new canvas and adjusting each pixels rgb value to match the color they selected on the first page. That page includes code somewhat like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   generateCanvas();
   $(".imageChoices").each(function() {
      changeColor(color);
   }
});
```

If I take the url from the first page: `page2.php?color=ff6600`and open the link in a new tab. Everything works fine! However, if I use the jQuery $.get function, then the javascript on my second page will never get triggered.

My question is, is this suppose to work this way? And, is there anyway that I can get the first page to trigger the second pages javascript functions? I tried this with PHP `file_get_contents` and I got the same result. I am looking for a way to make this work.

My backup plan is to use `header("location: page2.php?color=ff6600");` and then `window.location.href= "page1.php";` when page2 is complete. I am refraining from using this approach because they user will know they are being redirected to page2.

Comment: depends where your script is in second page. The `ready` and `load` events have already occurred in main page so code will fire immediately. If code preceeds the html, the elements don't exist yet

Comment: the code on the second page has to trigger after the images are loaded, so it is placed in the window.load function. The page works correctly if loaded normally, using $.get is not triggering anything in window.load

Comment: hey , i recommend you to use javascript `sessionStorage` it allow you to store value over html pages and make thoses data alive until browser to be close... easy to use it. take a look a mozilla documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: wait, so are you trying to trigger the javascript on `page2.php` from the ajax call in `page1.php`? That's what it sounds like you are saying to me. Ajax calls won't run javascript code on another page, you would actually get the source of the javascript. If you visit `page2.php` your browser will get that source and run it. An ajax call will get the source and make that the value passed into your success function.

Comment: @babar78 I can see its use, however the data I would need to store must be generated after the images are loaded, and those images have to be loaded on the second page.

Comment: if you need images to load will need to use an image preloader then to keep track of them, `window.load` was finished long ago in page you are inserting into with ajax. Also important to know where the script is. You may need `getScript` or use ajax `load()`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Thank you, that is what I thought was happening, because the same thing was happening with PHP file_get_contents. I looks like I will have to past the data onto the page or go with my backup plan

Comment: @DanceSC there are lots of ways to run your script. Best is usually to do it in ajax callback

Comment: You could open the page2 in an iframe for example. But both pages won't be able to communicate with each other easily. Why do you need a second page after all?

Comment: @charlietfl I can't use a preloader for this, because there are roughtly 1500~ images, and 12 image containers with the possibility of having any of one of those 1500 image.

Comment: yes, php's `file_get_contents` is not a browser. It will get you the source of a page, but won't parse that into what you see on screen or execute client side script.

Comment: @Rias I can't use an iframe because this will either be triggered when the form is submitted, or after the information is sent to the database page, before the header redirect.

Comment: @charlietfl I will try the ajax callback and let you know if that works!

Comment: what is the problem? try generate your image inside page 2 , and until response is available from inside Javascript page one , make pleoples waiting and render a loader.

Comment: Well to run JavaScript you will usually need a browser window. It's not possible to "trigger JavaScript" via a $.get. A $.get will only get you the markup of the page, without interpreting it in the browser. So, maybe you should explain more precisely what you want to achieve and what the limitations are.

Comment: @DanceSC yes you can use an image loading script, it would loop through whatever image tags exist and bind a load event to each one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, you cannot trigger a second page's javascript from the first page. I ended up having to create color folders for each of the images so that I could remove the second page (the page with the javascript to color each of the grey scaled images), and instead have the first page direct immediately to the final step of combining all of the colored images into one.

Comment: Then how does soundcloud tell tab 1 to stop playing once you press play in tab 2? I've never used it cross window (cross iframe though), but I think this also done using `postMessage`.

Comment: @m90 You are talking about cross tabs? There are ways to set up parent / child relationships. In the scenario above there is no second tab open, only 1 page. The idea was to include the content of another page, and activate that contents onload functions.